# How can I make Python see sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite, pysqlite

I cannot use sqlite3 (build python package), for the reason that `_sqlite3.so` file is missing. I found that people had the same problem and they resolved it [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/no-sqlite3.so-in-usrlibpython2.5lib-dynload-599027/). To solve my problem I have to "install `sqlite3` and recompile Python". I also found out that the problem can be solved by "building from source and moving the library to `/usr/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload/`".

As I have been told to here, I have to install sqlite from the source and copy newly compiled files to my Python directory (nothing was said about "recompile Python"). Well, I have installed sqlite and now I have to copy something to my `/lib-dynload/` directory.

I am not sure what exactly I should copy. In my `/lib-dynload/` directory I have only .so files. And in my `sqlite-3.6.18` I do not have any `*.so` files (it makes me suspicious). I had this problem since I did not have `_sqlite3.so` file in `/lib-dynload/`. By compilation of sqlite I got some new files (for example `sqlite3.o` and `sqlite3.lo`) but `not _sqlite3.so`.

P.S. Some details:

1. I use Python  2.6.2 (which I installed locally).

2. I do not have root permissions.

3. I had already sqlite installed globally on the machine by root.

4. I just installed sqlite locally.

5. My OS is CentOS release 5.3 (Final).

6. When I type in Python command line `import sqlite3` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/loctopu/opt/lib/python2.6/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "/home/loctopu/opt/lib/python2.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

Comment: When you did "make" of Python, you should have looked at the output at the point where it talks about sqlite, and corrected any errors it had reported.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have exact answer, but few hints here

- To install python from source, you don't need to be root, you can always install at `/home/USERNAME/usr`, for example when you do configure, do like `./configure --prefix=/home/USERNAME/usr`
- Installing sqlite binaries does not mean its included python extension (instead, sqlite dev files are needed when you compile python)
- proper import usage of sqlite3 is `import sqlite3`